# Specifying domain in sqsh

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sqsh

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server from a Linux terminal using SQSH. The line is:

```
sqsh -S <ip address> -U <DOMAIN\user>
```

which throws an error:

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1 Server 'DC2', Line 1
>   Login failed for user ''.

Notice that it seems to have removed the '\' which separates my domain and user.

On the server side, my event log confirms the same thing. The event reads:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAINuser'.
>   Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.

I've tried using single and double quotation marks to encapsulate the domain and user name, but when I do that, the request does not even make it to the server, probably because the quotes signify something else syntactically.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try two backslashes. In most linux / Unix iterations, a backslash is an escape character.

Comment: No dice. The request doesn't make it to the server when I tried it.

Comment: Have you tried setting it via $username variable?

Comment: DOH!  Use the format user@DOMAIN. That should work.

Comment: Login failed for user "user@DOMAIN". Reason Could not find a login matching the name provided. :(

Comment: Is this a Microsoft SQL Server in an Active Directory domain?  Do you have Samba or Centrify installed, or is your Linux server linked to your AD domain in any other way (such as via Kerberos)?

Comment: Correct, MS SQL Server is running in an AD domain. Linux server is undomained, and not running Centrify or Samba,

Answer (score 1):

sqsh uses the FreeTDS configuration file by default, so the version of TDS can be specified. A full description can be found [here](http://passing-the-hash.blogspot.com/2012/08/pth-with-mssql-and-freetdssqsh.html), but the command line result should look like this:

```
sqsh -S<config file name> -D <database name> -U <domain>\\<user> -P <password / hash>
```

Example:

```
sqsh -S mssql -D MyDB -U DOMAIN\\testuser -P MyTestingClearPassword1
```

Comment: When I enter the user as DOMAIN\\user, the connection request does not make it to the server - no failed login shows up in the Event Viewer log. However, if I type it in as DOMAIN\user, the login failure appears on the event log as before: Login failed for user 'DOMAINuser'.

Comment: I ended up bypassing this issue by creating a login directly through MSSQL Server Management Studio, thereby foregoing the need to specify a domain. Not sure if this will be limiting down the line, but I guess we'll see!